# Wpf template gallery

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls

Does anybody know of a gallery of controltemplates, that I could use to learn more about what is possible with the different control types?

Answer (score 1):

look at : https://github.com/jogibear9988/wpftoolkit

I've forked the Theming Package from Codeplex and switched to .Net 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with a gallery of control templates, though there are lots of examples on the internet.  If you have a specific control you'd like to template (e.g. a ListBox or a Button), I would search for specific control templates that relate to that control.  You will find countless options.

If you want to learn about what is possible with control templates, I'd suggest picking up one of the many great WPF books.  A few I'd recommend are:

- WPF Unleashed (by Adam Nathan)
- Applications = Code + Markup by (Charles Petzold)
- WPF Control Development Unleashed (by Pavan Podila and Kevin Hoffman)

You can completely recreate the visual tree of an element with a control template, so the possibilities are limitless.  You can also check out the MSDN Help Topics on control styles and templates:

- [Control Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx)
- [Using Templates to Customize WPF Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's this one

http://www.xamltemplates.net/

There's this one

http://www.reuxables.com/

There's this one

http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%203&referringTitle=Home

As a word of warning, all templates are not created equal - and not all templates will work across all XAML frameworks. For example if it is written for SL it may not work for WinRT. The same for WPF. But this list will get you started. In the end, you will probably create your own.